# Javascript: ideal chunk size for background tasks with setInterval?

Tags: javascript, settimeout, setinterval

Consider an application which periodically executes a background task via `setTimeout` / `setInterval`. What's the ideal amount of work one function call should do?

Example:

```
myTask = function() {
  for (var i=0; i<chunkSize; i++) { ...work... }
}

setInterval(myTask, period);
```

If you increase `chunkSize` (and do more iterations per call), of course it will run longer. That means, the `period` will also have to increase and you can call the function less often. But I found that nevertheless, the bigger the chunks, the more work gets done. This is probably due to overhead of `setTimeout` / `setInterval`

The trade-off is: bigger chunk sizes make the application less reactive. This does not only concern user interaction, but also other intervals. Because as long as the function is running its iterations, no other interval can get triggered. Thus, big chunk sizes make other intervals less accurate, or (in the worst case) completely disable them in some browsers so they don't get called anymore.

If you want to

- maximize the amount of work getting done
- minimize bad influence on other intervals and keep them accurate

what is the best way to achieve that? How do you determine a good chunkSize? Or should I monitor execution times in the loop and abort after a certain time? Or something else?

*(btw, this is about plain old JavaScript, not HTML5 WebWorkers)*

Comment: Why wouldn't you use worker threads for this? I'd personally go with reverse-AJAX, since callbacks are executed asynchronously in the first place, but I like to complicate things :D

Comment: Why not worker threads? 1) because they're not supported by older browsers. 2) because my jobs share data objects. That's not possible with a worker thread unless you keep serializing and de-serializing them which creates major overhead and sync problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can, you should use `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval`. `setInterval` will call the function after `period` whether the function from the previous interval is complete or not. With `setTimeout`, you can make sure the function is complete before it called again.

```
(function myTask() {
  for (var i=0; i<chunkSize; i++) { ...work... }
  setTimeout( myTask, period );
})();
```